# how do I clear entries in text boxes, visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

private: System::Void textBox1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{

```
    PNumberInputBox->Clear();
    PNumberOutputBox->Clear();
    DescriptionInputBox->Clear();
    DescriptionOutputBox->Clear();
    MNumberInputBox->Clear();
    MNumberOutputBox->Clear();
    WPInputBox->Clear();
    RPOutputBox->Clear();
    PercentInputBox->Clear();
    QuantityInputBox->Clear();
    QuantityOutputBox->Clear();
}
```

These are the code, but the system shows an error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX92H.png)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is managed C++ not 'regular' c++ judging by the ^ int he parameter list.

Comment: You can consult the documentation for [System.Windows.Forms.Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#properties) to see what operations are available. There is no method called `Clear`, but there is a property called [Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.text?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-label-text) which looks promising.

Comment: What type  PNumberInputBox is? Class Label? Please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You could use textBox.Text = String.Empty if using winform textbox.